# Group data based on different size

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to make a report in which I need to show data based on Width groups. Below is an example of data & the required output. I'm unable to make a group which can give this required output. If someone can help please.

[image]   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish your grouping needs for this data set would be to create a new Formula Field that evaluates the values of the Width data field for each record to determine which group the record belongs within, then do the grouping on this new formula field.

You formula field will look like this.

```
Select {WIDTH}
Case  400 to 600 :
"G1"
Case  601 to 849:
"G2"
Case  850 to 1049:
"G3"
Default :
"Default text or error message text goes here"
```

You will likely need to adjust the integer values I'm used in the Case statements to evaluate the WIDTH field.  The text that goes into the Default case is up to you.  In fact, if it works logically with your needs, you could eliminate the Default case entirely, as it is not required.  However, it is good practice to ensure the Switch statement always returns a value, even if that value is text to indicate that something unexpected occurred.  This allows your users to easily recognize a bit of a data that may be out of range for the grouping of the report so the report can be modified or the data can be corrected, whichever is the most appropriate action.

The other 3 columns in your required output appear to just be counting the number of records within each group that have a diameter within a range.  To get this output you can use Running Total Fields with a Type of summary of Count and then use the range of values in the Evaluate section.  The Reset section will be set to On change of group evaluating the group created by the formula field above.  You will want to put a sort order on the diameter field though.